# How to use QTimer

Tags: qt, timer

In Qt I'm trying to set a `QTimer` that calls a function called "update" every second. Here is my .cpp file:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QTimer>
#include "QDebug"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
    timer->start(1000);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::update()
{
    qDebug() << "update";
}
```

and the main:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

The project is being build, but it doesn't execute update, since the line "update" is not showing anywhere... Does anybody see what I´m doing wrong?

Comment: Are you calling `app.exec()` (or whatever you've called the `QApplication`) from `main`?

Comment: You are also creating a memory leak, add `this` to the `QTimer` constructor.

Comment: I added my main code. Adding this to the constructor hasn´t solved the problem.

Comment: @cmannett85 there is any memory leak, the MainWindow take the ownership of the timer, and when the MainWindow object be deleted, this will delete the timer on his destructor.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. It's good practice to give a parent to your `QTimer` to use Qt's memory management system.
2. `update()` is a *QWidget* function - is that what you are trying to call or not? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#update.
3. If number 2 does not apply, make sure that the function you are trying to trigger is declared as a slot in the header.
4. Finally if none of these are your issue, it would be helpful to know if you are getting any run-time connect errors.

Comment: Fixed it. The function apparently update() was not the best choise for the funtcion... When I changed it, it was fixed.

Comment: `update()` is overloaded several times, but the 'original' signature takes no arguments (scroll up slightly on the page you link to).  Please amend your answer.

Comment: `update` slot name works fine for me. Maybe the function has not been declared as a slot?

Answer (score 27):

Other way is using of built-in method start timer & event TimerEvent.

Header:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    int timerId;

protected:
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Source:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    timerId = startTimer(1000);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    killTimer(timerId);
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "Update...";
}
```

Comment: I tried everything to get QTimer to work - without success. But this worked immediately, thanks!!

Comment: This is exactly I was looking for hours now. Instant Success. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

mytimer.h:

```
    #ifndef MYTIMER_H
    #define MYTIMER_H

    #include <QTimer>

    class MyTimer : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        MyTimer();
        QTimer *timer;

    public slots:
        void MyTimerSlot();
    };

    #endif // MYTIME
```

mytimer.cpp:

```
#include "mytimer.h"
#include <QDebug>

MyTimer::MyTimer()
{
    // create a timer
    timer = new QTimer(this);

    // setup signal and slot
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()),
          this, SLOT(MyTimerSlot()));

    // msec
    timer->start(1000);
}

void MyTimer::MyTimerSlot()
{
    qDebug() << "Timer...";
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "mytimer.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    // Create MyTimer instance
    // QTimer object will be created in the MyTimer constructor
    MyTimer timer;

    return a.exec();
}
```

If we run the code:

```
Timer...
Timer...
Timer...
Timer...
Timer...
...
```

[resources](https://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QTimer.php)