# how to call a function every second which updates qt widget

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to qt development and facing a problem. I want to call a function updateCompass every 1 second which updates the compass value already drawn in widget.

I need to know how and where to call the function.

Comment: Look up QTimer. Also, I refuse to believe that you actually tried to search for this problem and you found nothing.

Comment: Don't be too harsh, @Matteo. When I entered `qt every second` into Google, only the first five links were relevant. Perhaps the OP was scared off by link six, which was some bizarre poetry from a Godophile :-)

Comment: And then you need `every two seconds` thus ask a whole different question.

Answer (score 10):

Qt has a specific method for doing exactly this, by using the [`QTimer` class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html).

It allows you to create a timer (one-shot or periodic) and connect its `timeout` signal to whatever slot (function) you need to weave your magic.

In fact, that linked page has *exactly* the code you need to use to perform your desired function:

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
timer->start(1000);
```

This will result in your `update` function being called once a second (within the limits imposed by Qt re accuracy and so on).

Answer (score 5):

Example, of your case.

```cpp
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);

QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateCompass()));

timer->start(1000);
```

This calls `updateCompass()` every second.

These links may be helpful to you. [QTimer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) & [Using QTimer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651852/how-to-use-qtimer)

Answer (score 1):

QTimer is ok for applications that don't care about update frequency (it can fluctuate).

For example, if you making an OpenGL program that updates each frame to animate something, you want to sync the update with the monitor's refresh rate (vsync).

To use vsync implement a class that derives from `QWindow` or `QOpenGLWindow`. Then at the end of your update function call `requestUpdate` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#requestUpdate

"[something about the update function] This is a slot so it can be connected to a QTimer::timeout() signal to perform animation. Note however that in the modern OpenGL world it is a much better choice to rely on synchronization to the vertical refresh rate of the display." - from https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwindow.html